# Are applications able to open ports in modem without permission?

Tags: router, permissions, port-forwarding, port, modem

Yesterday i logged into my modem's admin page and saw that some ports are open without my permission. There were 2 apps that were using these open ports EA and Whatsapp. I rarely connect to my modem, i use a router that's connected to my modem for my internet needs. The modem's admin panel is secured by a strong password. So i wonder how are these applications able to open ports without my permission. Its really strange. I have now closed these open ports (this is the 3rd time i am closing these ports) and applications are working fine including EA and whatsapp.

So My question is Are applications able to open ports in modem without permission? If yes then How do they do it without being able to login into modem's admin panel?

Comment: There is a feature called [upnp](https://www.howtogeek.com/122487/htg-explains-is-upnp-a-security-risk/) that allows applications to open ports automatically. There should be a way to turn it off in the settings of your modem.

Comment: If those ports were open they are likely required by one of your EA games and since you have WhatsApp installed on your PC.

Comment: @spiderpig Yes, upnp is enabled so you are right that may be allowing these applications to open these ports.

Comment: Related: [Found an application (Whatsapp) initiating UPnP requests, is it something that I should worry about?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/201173/47200)